# manipulate a property of a child element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following row element with a double click event atached to it.

```
<tr ondblclick="onLabelDoubleClicked(this)">
   <td><label id="labelId" >My Label</label></td>
   <td><input type="text" id="myInput" data-bind="kendoDropDownList: { data: source, value: myValue, enable: true }" /></td>
</tr>
```

On double click I need to set the `enable` property of `kendoDropDownList` in input element to toggle true/ false.

javascript:

```
onLabelDoubleClicked = function (event) {

    }
```

I searched through the `event` properties but could not find anything useful to get the `enable property` and manipulate it. Any help with working example will be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: That's not a property. `enable: true` are just characters in a string.

Comment: ...is this part of some other API? If so, doesn't it give you some way to enable/disable elements?

Comment: It [is](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/dropdownlist). And I wouldn't even call 'XY problem' here, as the OP doesn't say how exactly he needs this property to be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use jQuery (and tag sets implies you're), why not just use jQuery (and Kendo) methods?

```
$('tr').dblclick(function() {
  var $kd = $(this).find('input').data("kendoDropDownList");
  $kd.enable( $kd.element.is(':disabled') );
});
```

Comment: You are right! This is the way to manipulate this. But toggle does something different. I want on double click to enable/disable the dropdown. How can I do this? I am quite new to jquery and kendoui.

Comment: @Mdb I see, you can check `.enable` property then. Will update the answer with example.

Comment: @Mdb Sigh... Somehow either I'm bad at parsing documentations (but I'm usually not) or KendoUI indeed doesn't have a getter for this property. I had to go with checking `element` instead, but I'd certainly prefer more 'API'sh way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of inlining the doubleclick event, it’s easier if you put the handler in the JS code and traverse/change the DOM from there.

I’m not sure about the Kendo stuff in the `data-bind` property, but it looks like a string to me so you’ll need to do string replaces unless you have a better way.

try this:

```
$('tr').dblclick(function() {
    var $el = $(this).find(':text'),
        data = $el.data('bind');
    if (/true/.test(data)) {
        data = data.replace(/true/,'false');
    } else if (/false/.test(data)) {
        data = data.replace(/false/,'true');
    }
    $el.prop('data-bind', data);
});
```

Comment: With all due respect - yuk. What if there's more than one boolean value here, in that dataset? Why not just use `.data` method, if you don't want to let Kendo solve this?

Comment: I agree... it’s just that I don’t see another way unless this Kendo thing can solve it within it’s API. But that information is not provided in the question.