# Disable kendo numerictextbox widget on double click using the kendoui and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendonumerictextbox

I have this html. On double click I want to disable/enable the dropdown:

```
<tr>
   <td><label id="labelId" >My Label</label></td>
   <td><input type="text" id="myInput" data-bind="kendoDropDownList: { data: source, value: myValue, enable: true }" /></td>
</tr>
```

I was able to do this with the solution from here [manipulate a property of a child element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13255277/manipulate-a-property-of-a-child-element) using the kendo Api:

```
$('tr').dblclick(function() {
  var $kd = $(this).find('input').data("kendoDropDownList");
  $kd.enable( $kd.element.is(':disabled') );
});
```

I have a kendoui numeric widget. It seems that kendoui framework is adding some additional html elements and the final html looks like this:

```
<tr>
       <td><label id="labelId" >My Label</label></td>
       <td><input class="k-formatted-value k-input" style="display: inline-block;" type="text" readOnly="readonly"/>
           <input name="Afk" class="k-input" id="Afk" style="display: none;" type="text" data-bind="kendoNumericTextBox: { value: Afk, min:1, max:10000, step:1, format: 'd'}" data-role="numerictextbox" required=""/>
        <td>
    </tr>
```

I tried this:

```
$('tr').dblclick(function () {
        var $ntb = $(this).find('input').data("kendoNumericTextBox");

        $ntb.enable($ntb.element.is(':disabled'));
    });
```

But this does not work I think because there are two inputs. My questions is how can I enable/disable the numeric widget on doubleclick similar to the way the kendodropdown is disabled?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can filter for `data-role` attribute so you can select your desired `input`, like this:

```
$('tr').dblclick(function () {
    var $ntb = $(this).find('input[data-role="numerictextbox"]').data("kendoNumericTextBox");

    $ntb.enable($ntb.element.is(':disabled'));
});
```

Comment: I did something similar but searched for name attribute ... anyway I like your way more.

Answer (score 5):

```
 var numerictextbox = $("#numerictextbox").data("kendoNumericTextBox");

 numerictextbox.enable();

 numerictextbox.enable(false);
```

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/numerictextbox/api[enter link description here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/numerictextbox/api)

Comment: much cleaner and a more elegant solution.